# How to build an external c++ library (static or shared) for android?

Tags: android, c++, static, android-ndk, java-native-interface

***How to build an external c++ library (static or shared) for android?***

Hi,

currently I am trying to use JNI to call a c++ library from my android app.
A simple example in which I just implemented the c++ files generated by jni directly, works fine.

Now I want to generate an external c++ library and call that in the jni c++ implementation.
So that the jni implementation just defines the interface and the whole functionality is located in the external static c++ library.

For this I create a c++ project using eclipse (ubuntu 32bit).

The project structure is like the following:

```
     StaticLibraryTest
        -> src
                -> bean -> Point
                -> util -> Math
                        -> StringUtil
```

The project just implements simple methods for testing.

Now I have the question: How to build this project so that I can use it in the jni c++ implementation. I got problems on executing ndk-build.

My jni folder looks like:

```
 NativeTestProject 
    -> jni
            -> calc -> de_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface.h
                    -> de_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface.cpp

    -> inc
            -> **/*.h(all header files from the external StaticLibraryTest library)

    -> libStaticLibraryTest.a (my external library)
    -> Application.mk (just containing the line: APP_ABI := all)
    -> Android.mk
```

Android.mk contains the following lines:

```
 
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE    := libStaticLibraryTest
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libStaticLibraryTest.a
    include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := calc/de_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface.cpp 
    LOCAL_MODULE     := de_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libStaticLibraryTest
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I would be very happy if somebody can help me to find the right way.

Edit:

I think i made the next step. I created the external static library with arm-linux-gnueabi and now i got the following error executing ndk-build:

```
$ ndk-build
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : de_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface <= de_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface.cpp
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libde_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface.so
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status
/cygdrive/k/android-ndk64-r10-windows-x86_64/build/core/build-binary.mk:647: recipe for target 'obj/local/arm64-v8a/libde_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface.so' failed
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libde_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface.so] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'obj/local/arm64-v8a/libde_tl_calc_SharedLibraryInterface.so'
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libStaticLibraryTest.a` for declaring your prebuilt static library.
That means this .a file will be used when compiling for all the architectures supported by the NDK, but this cannot work since you need to have a different one per architecture.

You should compile your .a for all the supported architectures and put it under subfolders (armeabi-v7a, x86, arm64-v8a, x86_64...), so you can include it properly using something like this:

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilts/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libStaticLibraryTest.a`